# Can not assign value to a variable

Tags: python, cs50

```
def simulate_tournament(teams):
    """Simulate a tournament. Return name of winning team."""
    # If only one team left
    if len(teams) == 1:
        # Assigns the only element of type dictionary of the list to a variable
        winner = teams[0]
        # Gets value of the firs key(name a team)
        i = list(winner.values())[0]
        # Returns name of the team type <'class str'>
        return i

    else:
        # Calls function to simulate a game between each pair of teams and returns list of winners
        winners = simulate_round(teams)
        # Using recursion to simulate all games in order to get the base case
        simulate_tournament(winners)
```

Example of a dictionary element

```
team = {
    "name": "Germany"
    "rating": 1000
}
```

But when I try no assign a return value to a variable in my main function and try to print it:

```
winner = simulate_tournament(teams)
print(winner)
```

It prints **None**

Comment: If `len(teams) != 1` you return nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return your recursive call. Without `return`, you're just calling the function and discarding the value returned.

```
def simulate_tournament(teams):
    """Simulate a tournament. Return name of winning team."""
    # If only one team left
    if len(teams) == 1:
        # Assigns the only element of type dictionary of the list to a variable
        winner = teams[0]
        # Gets value of the firs key(name a team)
        i = list(winner.values())[0]
        # Returns name of the team type <'class str'>
        return i

    else:
        # Calls function to simulate a game between each pair of teams and returns list of winners
        winners = simulate_round(teams)
        # Using recursion to simulate all games in order to get the base case
        return simulate_tournament(winners)
```